# URL Scheme facebook page post

Tags: facebook, url

How do I use the url scheme to facebook from a link in the mobile browser open the facebook app on a specific post of a page?

In href tried using:

fb://page/"id" - opens the page correctly

tried using fb://post/"id_post" - does not work, just open the facebook app

Comment: There is no documented way of doing it